# Can I use Dart web package flutter project?

Tags: flutter, dart, package

I'm working on flutter app for weather forecast. I have chosen Dark Sky API to work with and I found [darksky_weather](https://pub.dev/packages/darksky_weather#-readme-tab-) package on [Dart Packages Site](https://pub.dev) to make things easier. The package is marked with **web** tag. Can I use this package with flutter project as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to use it as it does not depend on any web specific package.
It just depends on the `http` package which can be used in any dart project, no matter if it's just dart or flutter.

Just install the darksky_weather package by adding it to pubspec.yaml and follow the example.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.